# 2D RGB image construction from 3D array in SimpleITK

Tags: python, image, simpleitk

I have an RGB image in the format of a 3D array with the shape of (m, n, 3). I would like to create a SimpleITK image. Using the **GetImageFromArray()** function results in creation of an image in 3D which is not what I am looking for. How can I create a 2D RGB image instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation reads:

> Signature: sitk.GetImageFromArray(arr, isVector=None)
>
> Docstring: Get a SimpleITK Image from a numpy array. If isVector is True, then the Image will have a Vector pixel type, and the last dimension of the array will be considered the component index. By default when isVector is None, 4D images are automatically considered 3D vector images.

Have you tried passing `isVector=True`?